# how to find out the size of a std::bitset at compile time

Tags: c++

Is there a way to find out size of a `std::bitset`?

I have

```
 typedef std::bitset<64> Bitset;
```

and I want to know the size without creating an instance. Eg. like `Bitset::size`

When I look to the sources in `bitset.h` it is totally unreadable to me, but even though I found these lines

```
public:
    enum {_EEN_BITS = _Bits};   
    typedef _Bitset_base<_Bits <= 8 ? 1
        : _Bits <= 16 ? 2
        : _Bits <= 32 ? 4
        : 8> _Mybase;
    typedef typename    // sic
        _Mybase::_Ty _Ty;
```

which I thought tell me, that `_Ty` can contain size, but when I try to call `Bitset::_Ty` i get `illegal use of this type as an expression`

I know I can store the size somewhere before I typedef the bitset but that is not what I want.

Comment: Number of bits should be in the enum value `_EEN_BITS`, but I cannot check it, because I don't have this declaration in my implementation of the standard library.

Comment: @RafałRawicki it is, but I assume this is not much portable, which I need

Comment: Unfortunately. C++ std library isn't perfect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Bitset::digits` instead, which corresponds to 64 in your case.

EDIT: As that turned out wrong, here's a different solution:

```
template< typename T >
struct GetSize;

template< size_t Len > 
struct GetSize< std::bitset< Len > >
{
    enum { Length = Len };
};
```

Used such as:

```
const size_t bitsetLength = GetSize< std::bitset< 1024 > >::Length;
```

Comment: thank you, but I am getting `'digits' : is not a member of 'std::bitset<_Bits>'`

Comment: I don't think the standard specifies anything about bitset<N>::digits.

Comment: Yeah, upon further examination it would seem it's both not in the standard, and private to boot in MSVC.

Answer (score 3):

As every C++ standard library container `std::bitset` has `size()` method. In most cases using `size()` is fine, because it will be inlined by the compiler.

In C++03 there is no public member you can use, for example when parametrizing other template.

Because `size()` method is declared as a `constexpr` you can use it to parametrize a template in C++11, just like that:

```
 std::bitset<34> b;
 std::bitset<b.size()> bx;
```

Standard still doesn't define any member of the `std::bitset<N>` you can use portably. In your question there is a fragment which defines `enum {_EEN_BITS = _Bits};`, so that `std::bitset<N>::_EEN_BITS` should equal to `N`, but this is available only in Visual Studio.

Comment: thank you, but I want to know it without creating an instance

Comment: Thank you. but I think the answer to my question is that is not possible to get size without creating an instance

Answer (score 3):

Just use `std::bitset<n>().size()` just like Rafał Rawicki suggests in his answer.

The compiler will optimize the temporary instance away (when compiled with -O2) :

```
76:test.cpp      ****     int i = std::bitset<8>().size();
77:test.cpp      **** 
78:test.cpp      ****     std::cout << i << std::endl;
68                      .loc 1 78 0
69 0009 C7442404        movl    $8, 4(%esp) #,
69      08000000 
70 0011 C7042400        movl    $_ZSt4cout, (%esp)  #,
70      000000
71 0018 E8FCFFFF        call    _ZNSolsEi   #
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, template argument deduction works fine:

`template<size_t N> char (&getBitsetSize(std::bitset<N>))[N];`

Usage: `sizeof(getBitsetSize(Bitset());`

C++03 solution, for C++11 use Rafał Rawicki's answer.

Comment: He has this thing about not creating an instance. I think Ylisar's updated answer is better.

Comment: @juanchopanza: This doesn't create an instance. The argument _type_ to `sizeof` is determined by the compiler at compile time; the argument itself is never evaluated.

Comment: Interesting. Is that guaranteed, or does it rely on an optimization?

Comment: Guaranteed. As you see, I don't even have to provide a definition of the function, since it's not called.